# Reload page but don't add to history stack

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, express, browser

I am very new to **HTML, node.js, Jquery, and Express.js**, which are the technologies I am using right now for a web project.

I am having issues with reloading a page after submitting a form.

The flow of the page is that the user chooses in the home page to see a record, they click on it, and this redirects them to another html file where they can see all the details about the record. When they click on an edit button, they are able to edit the record using a **form tag**. When they click submit, my server currently performs the changes to the record and then uses **response.redirect(http://page-where-user-can-see-record)** to reload the record page (the one they were editing the record just a second ago) so that the user can see the record with the new changes right after submitting the form. The issue is that now, if the user submits several edits at once, they'll have to click the back button several times before reaching the home page again.

Is there a way to prevent this? So that, even if they're redirected to the record page several times, they can reach the home button with only one click on the back button?

Comment: You should study up on manipulation of web browser history -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Comment: You may also want to perform your submissions with something like $.post (or any other framework equivalent, if you prefer to avoid jQuery) to provide a better user experience.